# Split layout in Google's default keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, gboard

According to [this Droid Life post](http://www.droid-life.com/2015/06/01/android-m-feature-google-added-a-split-keyboard-for-tablets/) from Jun 1st 2015, Android M introduced the split layout to the default keyboard by Google.

I have a Moto G3 with Android v6.0 and the "Enable split keyboard" option shown below, is not available.

[image]

Was this feature ever added? Perhaps in an update to v6.0 I might not have yet?

Comment: It is specific to tablets only it appears.

Comment: Can you confirm you have a tablet with v6.0 and this option available and/or a cell with v6.0 and this option *not* available?

Comment: I don't see the option on my Nexus 6, plus the article you linked the headline reads "Android M Feature: Google Added a Split Keyboard for Tablets".  I do not have a tablet running Android M.

Comment: That could be it then. Would you like to post your comment as an answer?

Comment: Sure, I will do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This applies to tablets running Android M only at this time, as on my Nexus 6 running Android M the option does not appear.

Thanks to @Firelord for this [Android Police](http://www.androidpolice.com/2015/05/29/android-m-feature-spotlight-the-stock-keyboard-now-has-a-split-screen-mode-on-larger-devices/) link and information:

> "Here's the thing, though: you won't find this option on phones."